# Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'Db' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite, dart-async

i am using this DbProvider class in many other files. it throws error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
> LateInitializationError: Field 'Db' has not been initialized.
>
> E/flutter (12867): #0      DbProvider.Db (package:sample/src/Db.dart)
>
> E/flutter (12867): #1      Bloc.fetchInfoWithNameOrder
> (package:sample/src/bloc.dart:31:24)
>
> E/flutter (12867): #2      NameTiles.build.
> (package:sample/src/NameTiles.dart:20:16)
>
> E/flutter (12867): #3      StreamBuilder.build
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:546:81)

This is DbProvider class

```
class DbProvider{
  late Database Db;
  DbProvider(){init();}
  
  init()async{
    print("sdsdfaf");
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(dir.path, 'AppDb.db');
    print(dir.path);
    Db = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database newDb, int version){
        newDb.execute(
          """
          create table Names(
            id integer primary key,
            name text,
            Salary integer,
            total integer
          );

          create table Att(
            id integer primary key,
            name text,
          );
          """
        );
      }
    );

    print('\n\n\ndb init\n\n\n');
  }
}
```

This is bloc.dart file

```
class Bloc{
  final db = DbProvider();
  final _text_field_subject = BehaviorSubject();
  final _tile = BehaviorSubject();
  
  Function(String?) get addToTextSubject => _text_field_subject.sink.add;
  Stream get text_field_subject => _text_field_subject.stream;
  get text_field_subject_value => _text_field_subject.value;

  Function get addToTile => _tile.sink.add;
  Stream get tile => _tile.stream;

  fetchInfo(String arg) async{
    print('\nfetchInfo\n');
    var ans = await db.Db.query(
      "Names",
      where: "name = ?",
      whereArgs: [arg],
    );
    print(ans);
    addToTile(ans);
  }

  fetchInfoWithNameOrder()async{
    print('\nfetchinfowithorder\n');
    var ans = await db.Db.query(
      "Names",
      orderBy: "name asc",
    );
    print(ans);
    addToTile(ans);
  }
}
```

and here is the NameTiles class with builder:

```
class NameTiles extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('\n\n\n1\n\n\n');
    final db = DbProvider();
    print('\n\n\n3\n\n\n');
    final bloc = StreamProvider.of(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.tile,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot? snapshot){
        print('\n\n\nre\n\n\n');  
        if(snapshot == null || !snapshot.hasData){
          print('\n\n\nStarting\n\n\n');
          bloc.fetchInfoWithNameOrder();
          return Text('loading');
        }
        print('\n\n\ntween\n\n\n');
        return Text('llll');
      },
    );
    
  }

  Widget tiles(info){
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      child: Row(children: [
        Text('${info.name}'),
        Text('${info.total}'),
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `init` in your constructor, but you never wait for it to finish.

So your constructor runs, it trigers the `init` method, and while that runs, since it's `async` and has no `await` to wait for it, your program continues, finally coming to a part where your variable is needed, but not initialized yet, since `init` is still running.

Some tips:

1. crank up warnings to a maximum, maybe using a package like `pedantic`
2. actually provide return types for your async methods
3. move your construction of DbProvider out of your build method
4. instead of having a constructor, create a factory method and make it async, remember to provide a proper return type and call it with an `await`.

You may want to read up on [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)